# Modal Pop Up not saving to db when button inside is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, popup

I am new with jquery and ajax, so please be patient.
I have this link:

```
   <a href="#message" style="text-decoration:none" class="common2 simple3" >Message</a>
```

that shows this pop up when clicked:

```
  <div id="message" class="modalDialog">
       <div>        
            <h3>Create A Message</h3>
            <form id="msgForm" name="msgForm" action="#" method="post">
                <textarea  id = 'msgContent' cols="48" rows="10" ></textarea>
                    <br>
                    <div id="create_btn">
                        <a href='' id = 'send' class="common simple2" style='margin-left:50px;text-decoration: none;'>Send</a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="cancel_btn">
                        <a href="#close" class="common simple2" style='margin-left:40px;text-decoration: none;'>cancel</a>
                    </div>
             </form>
        </div>
   </div>
```

when I entered text in the textarea and show its content by alert(msgContent) in the script below, it shows

```
  $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#send").click(function(e) 
        {   
            e.preventDefault();
            var msgContent = $("#msgContent").val();
            alert(msgContent);
                $.ajax({
                url: 'message.php?message='+ msgContent,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                context: this,
                success: function(result)
                        {                                           

                            //if (result == true)
                            $(this).html('Send');   
                        } 
                });


        })
    })
```

but when I try to pass it to a php page through ajax, it won't pass. What could be wrong?

this is message.php

```
   $message = $_POST['message'];
   $result = false;
   $sql="INSERT INTO MESSAGE_LOG (sender,recepient, message)
          VALUES($viewer,$viewed,$message)";
    if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }
```

Comment: Please, elaborate.. what do you mean with _it won't pass_ ?

Comment: i can't get msgContent pass to message.php

Comment: Can you post the code to what's in message.php?

Comment: Also, waht do you mean by "pass a PHP page through ajax"? Do you want PHP to respond with some HTML that you display?

Comment: i need to pass msgContent to a php page so i can save data in database without redirecting the page

Comment: I should really warn you about the SQL injection attack vulnerability.  http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JS should be this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#send").click(function(e)  {   
        e.preventDefault();
        var msgContent = $("#msgContent").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'message.php',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {message: msgContent},
            context: this,
            success: function(result) {                                           
                alert('Message has been sent');  
            } 
        });
    });
});
```

And your PHP this:

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
$result = false;
$sql="INSERT INTO MESSAGE_LOG (sender,recepient, message)
      VALUES($viewer,$viewed,'$message')";
if (!mysqli_query($connection,$sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
```

Comment: but is there a way that i can show a pop up saying "Message been sent" rather than changing the 'Send' button to 'Sent'?

Comment: i tried adding that in success: function(result){if (result == true) alert('Message been sent');} but it didn't show up, or i need to insert it elsewhere?

Comment: hi!.. i am updating Message has been sent alert. Is there a way that i can show this message in another pop up? i have inserted a <div id="success">
       Message has been sent.
     </div>  in <div id = "message"> and called it in ajax success : $('#success').open(); but i shows simultaneously with my message pop up.

Comment: @Nhiz then just comment out the line: alert('Message has been sent');

Comment: the Message has been sent pop up is simultaneously appearing with the pop up with the text area. So even before i write in the text area, the other pop appears

Comment: @Nhiz I don't understand you entirely, you should post this matter in another question, so all the community can help you

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the value from `$_GET`:

```
$message = $_GET['message'];
```

Or use the post method, with data attribute:

```
 $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#send").click(function(e) 
        {   
            e.preventDefault();
            var msgContent = $("#msgContent").val();
            alert(msgContent);
                $.ajax({
                url: 'subscribe.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {message: msgContent},
                //dataType: 'json', from your php I don't that that you are looking for json response...
                context: this,
                success: function(result)
                        {                                           

                            //if (result == true)
                            $(this).html('Send');   
                        } 
                });


        })
    })
```

Comment: i changed $_POST['message']; to $_POST['message']; but nothing changed. I also tried the post method and result is the same